# Change side menu items dynamically in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm migrating a project from ionic 3.2 to 5.14, and I'm having trouble using observables instead of events.

In the original code, after the user logged in, I changed the name and image of the sidemenu through events:

**app.component.ts**

```
this.events.publish('user:login', this.nomePrimeiro, Date.now());
this.events.publish('image:login', this.imagem, Date.now());
```

and on **app.component.ts** I wrote this:

```
events.subscribe('user:login', (user, time) => {
  Global.nomePrimeiro = user;
});

events.subscribe('image:login', (image, time) => {
  Global.imagem = image;
});
```

How to change this for Observables?
I will need a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create event service.
In the EventService.ts:

```
export class EventService {
        private dataObserved = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
        currentEvent = this.dataObserved.asObservable();
        constructo(){}
        
        publish(param):void {
          this.dataObserved.next(param);
        }
}
```

For publishing the event from example page1:

```
constructor(public eventService:EventService){}
    updatePost(){
    this.eventService.publish('post:updated');
    // or 
    this.eventService.publish({name: 'postupdate', value: 'value you need to pass'});
}
```

In page 2:

```
constructor(public eventService:EventService){
      this.eventService.currentEvent.subscribe(data=>{
     // here you can get the data or do whatever you want or data.name or data.value
    
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mostafa. This is what I needed, a simple and clear example of how to use observables.